# Three mutually-tangent circles have centers at given distances from each other; find each radius, and find the area between the circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Three circles of different radii are tangent to each other externally. The distance between their centers are $9\ cm$, $8\ cm$, and $11\ cm$.

1. Find the radius of each circle.
2. Find the area in between the three circles.

> The distance between the centers of two tangent circles should be the sum of their radii. If we call the radii $r_1,r_2,r_3$ then we get a system of equations $$\begin{align}r_1+r_2&=9\\r_2+r_3&=8\\r_3+r_1&=11\end{align}$$ From this we can find $r_1,r_2,r_3$.
>
> Let us call $O_1,O_2,O_3$ the centers of the circles. For the area between the centers we could compute it as the difference of the area of the triangle $O_1O_2O_3$ minus the three circular sectors that the circles cover. We have the area of the triangle because we have its sides $9,8,11$ and we could use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) with them. For the circular sectors we know their radii but we also need their amplitude. Ah, but the amplitude is the same as the angles of the triangle. I guess we can compute the angles, because we have the sides of the triangle and we can use [The law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to solve for the angles.

Is this correct?

Would I have to use the $\arccos(x)$ function to get the final answer or there is a simpler way?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: The first time I read the title I thought it said "Solid menstruation (cycles)".

Comment: $(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(6,3,5)$, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Solving for the radii, we get $\{3,5,6\}$.

For the area we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{14(14-8)(14-9)(14-11)}\\[9pt]
&-\frac{(8+9-11)^2}8\arccos\left(\frac{8^2+9^2-11^2}{2\cdot8\cdot9}\right)\\
&-\frac{(11+8-9)^2}8\arccos\left(\frac{11^2+8^2-9^2}{2\cdot11\cdot8}\right)\\
&-\frac{(9+11-8)^2}8\arccos\left(\frac{9^2+11^2-8^2}{2\cdot9\cdot11}\right)
\end{align}
$$
which is $3.05537320587455$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* solving for 3 variables.

```
Clear[a, b, c];
Solve[9 - a == b && 8 - b == c && 11 - c == a, {a, b, c}]

(* {{a -> 6, b -> 3, c -> 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do this:

(a) construct a triangle $ABC$ with sides $8, 9$ and $11.$

(b) find the incenter $I$ of $ABC$

(c) the common value $AI = BI = CI$ is the radius you want.

the same can be done algebraically by finding

(a) two angles using the cosine rule

(b) use herons formula to find the area of $ABC$

(c) in-radius = $\dfrac{area}{semi perimeter}$

(d) $AI = \dfrac{r}{\tan A/2}$